# android-crop library- outputUri is always null value

Tags: android

I am using android-crop as per the directions given here https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/205#!description

The `outputUri` is always `null`,  what might be the reason?

```
 String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
        File createDir = new File(root+"ma"+File.separator);
        createDir.mkdir();


        File file = new File(root + "ma" + File.separator +"ma.jpg");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Crop.of(imageUri, outputUri.fromFile(file)).asSquare().start(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the below code in `onActivityresult.`

```
outputUri = Crop.getOutput(data);
```

Note: `data` is intent.